# Flatlist Header on the base of key React native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

```
const data = [
   {
    "name": "AAXx",
    "number" "111111"
    "type": "employee",
   },
   {
    "name": "bbbs",
    "number" "2222"
    "type": "employee",
   },
   {
    "name": "xxx",
    "number" "3333"
    "type": "students",
   },
]

<FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={item => item.number }
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text> {item.name}</Text>
/>
```

**Current result**

AAXx

bbbs

xxx

**Expected Result**

**employe**

AAXx

bbbs

**students**

xxx

I already try *ListHeaderComponent* but i want this on the base of key (type).
How can i achieve expected result with this data set.

Thanks.

Comment: What you need seems to be a sectionlist rather than a flatlist i think.

Comment: Section list i already read. but how can i achieve with this data set?

Answer (score 1):

You need a [**SectionList**](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) rather than a FlatList.

And you also need to group your data into [**sections**](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#sections) so that SectionList can understand how it should list items under which sections.

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: 'employee',
    data: [{
      name: 'AAXx',
      number: '111111',
    },
    {
      name: 'bbbs',
      number: '2222',
    }],
  },
  {
    title: 'students',
    data: [{
      name: 'xxx',
      number: '3333',
    },
    ],
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <SectionList
      sections={DATA}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.number}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.name} />}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
      )}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

https://snack.expo.io/@nicefella82/sectionlist-example

Comment: How can i convert my data into sections?
like yours.

Comment: This is another subject which is to group an array of objects by key. Take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key

Comment: @Nostromo please here is my issue check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75053910/how-to-set-header-in-alphabetic-way-in-react-native