# How to set header in Alphabetic way in react native?

Tags: reactjs, database, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

## **output**

[image]

## **code**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';

import { nameData } from './dummydata';

const windowSize = FlatList.length > 50 ? FlatList.length / 4 : 21;

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{}}>
      <SafeAreaView style={{}}>
        <ScrollView style={{}}>

          <FlatList
            disableVirtualization={true}
            //data={nameData.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))}
            data={nameData.sort(function (a, b) {
              return (a.name < b.name) ? -1 : (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : 0;
            })}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 20,marginLeft:10,padding:5 }}>{item.name}</Text>
            )}
          
            getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
            length: 80,
            offset: 80 * index,
            index,
            })}
            removeClippedSubviews={true}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={windowSize}
            windowSize={windowSize}
            numColumns={1}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
            contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 10 }}
          />

        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

**I have given the code above**

my data is sorted , I want like this if data is started A alphabet then this data contain in A header section if data is started B alphabet then this data contain in B header section.

like this D header contain only D Starting data C header contain only C Starting data

but I don't know how to set header and how to  set data in header section.

in sort I want like this data

[image]

anybody can give me solution?

**thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

Try this package [react-native-section-alphabet-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-section-alphabet-list)

A simple React Native component that takes an array of data and renders a SectionList with alphabetically (or custom) sorted data.

[image]

**Method 2**

Update your code like below and try

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, FlatList, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";

import { nameData } from "./duumydata";

const windowSize = FlatList.length > 50 ? FlatList.length / 4 : 21;

const Main = () => {
  let listData = new Array(26).fill([]);
  const headerArray = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    nameData.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.name.toUpperCase() < b.name.toUpperCase()
        ? -1
        : a.name > b.name
        ? 1
        : 0;
    });
    headerArray.forEach((header, index) => {
      nameData.forEach((item) => {
        const headerText = item.name.split("")[0].toUpperCase();
        if (header == headerText) {
          listData[index] = [...listData[index], item];
        }
      });
    });
    setData(listData);
  }, []);

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
          <Text>{headerArray[index]}</Text>
        </View>
        {item?.map((obj) => renderName(obj))}
      </>
    );
  };

  const renderName = (item) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{}}>
      <SafeAreaView style={{}}>
        <FlatList
          disableVirtualization={true}
          data={data}
          renderItem={(item) => renderItem(item)}
          getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
            length: 80,
            offset: 80 * index,
            index
          })}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={windowSize}
          windowSize={windowSize}
          numColumns={1}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 10 }}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: I'm try this but my data is more then 1000 so its give me blank screen when I'm fast scrolling in last data see here https://github.com/Kieran-McIntyre/react-native-section-alphabet-list/issues/23

Comment: can you able to add header in flatlist??

Comment: Try optimizing the list by passing these props mentioned here : https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Comment: it's not related to header may be

Comment: Blank screen is a reported issue in `FlatList` for large data

Comment: my data is come properly in Fltlist just I want header you have any idea about it

Comment: If you can create and share the link of snack expo of the above, I will try some logic

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-gattu-patel-forked-v3s5sh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: have you seen code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250964/discussion-between-gattu-patel-and-zfloc-technologies).

Comment: @GattuPatel please check method 2 in updated answer

Comment: it will give me a header but header is hide when I scroll I won't like this header is stay in screen when I scroll up or down scroll

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QZzK9GS see here

Comment: It's not scrollable from codesandbox. Anyway I have updated the logic. Please try with updated code above @GattuPatel

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ncomfDh here why this data come like this after a mint it's will give me data like this https://imgur.com/a/CzJMFFT I want direct like 2 img

Comment: have you seen ?

Comment: Forget to set & pass data in state. That's why data updating issue. Please check the updated code now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067444/how-to-add-header-sticky-in-existing-flatlist-in-react-native please check this